# Format bytes to kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes

Tags: php

Scenario: the size of various files are stored in a database as bytes. What's the best way to format this size info to kilobytes, megabytes and gigabytes? For instance I have an MP3 that Ubuntu displays as "5.2 MB (5445632 bytes)". How would I display this on a web page as "5.2 MB" AND have files less than one megabyte display as KB and files one gigabyte and above display as GB?

Comment: I belive you should create a function doing this. Just divide number by 1024 and look at result. If its more then 1024 then divide again.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

```
function formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2) { 
    $units = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'); 
   
    $bytes = max($bytes, 0); 
    $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1024)); 
    $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1); 
   
    // Uncomment one of the following alternatives
    // $bytes /= pow(1024, $pow);
    // $bytes /= (1 << (10 * $pow)); 
   
    return round($bytes, $precision) . $units[$pow]; 
}
```

(Taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filesize.php), there are many other examples there, but I like this one best :-)

Comment: I almost upvoted your answer (it's very similar to mine), but I don't like this "division by 1024^$pow" business. You should just do 1024^fraction($pow) and be done. :-)

Comment: If you used `$bytes /= (1 << (10 * $pow))` or the like, I could like it better. :-P

Comment: There you go :D (personally, I don't like bitwise arithmetic, because it is hard to understand if you aren't used to it...)

Comment: `9287695` returns `8.86 MB` with a precision of 2. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Justin that's because 9287695 / 1024 / 1024 is indeed 8,857 :)

Comment: Actually, it's `KiB`, `MiB`, `GiB` and `TiB` since you are dividing by `1024`. If you divided by `1000` it would be without the `i`.

Comment: `$bytes /= (1 << (10 * $pow))` does not work well but number above 1 TB

Comment: Just FYI, the second alternative above calculates TB wrong as David Belanger also pointed out.  Use the first alternative instead ($bytes /= pow(1024, $pow);)

Comment: use return round($bytes, $precision) . '&nbsp;' . $units[$pow];  if you never want the unit being pushed onto the next line in HTML output.

Comment: `Uncomment one of the following alternatives` was something I did not notice for 5 minutes ...

Comment: Why is `$bytes = max($bytes, 0);` used here?

Comment: @yogur, it is so that if $bytes is a negative value, it will set it to 0 instead.

Comment: Do not forget to uncomment one of the two lines stated in the code.

Comment: `return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ' . $units[$pow]; ` needs to be `return round($pow, $precision) . ' ' . $units[$pow]; `. Isn't it? check:- https://3v4l.org/3GEig AND https://3v4l.org/gqE3D

Comment: if you are working with WordPress, you can use the shared function `size_format()`.

Comment: Does not work out of the box (just tried copy-pasting without checking comments). I would ask the author to adapt the code so that it does (uncomment one of the two options). Until then I recommend this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510540/1240678

Answer (score 247):

This is Chris Jester-Young's implementation, cleanest I've ever seen, combined with php.net's and a precision argument.

```
function formatBytes($size, $precision = 2)
{
    $base = log($size, 1024);
    $suffixes = array('', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T');   

    return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), $precision) .' '. $suffixes[floor($base)];
}

echo formatBytes(24962496);
// 23.81M

echo formatBytes(24962496, 0);
// 24M

echo formatBytes(24962496, 4);
// 23.8061M
```

Comment: it has 2 errors
- add 1 to (at least small) files size
- not working with 0 (return NAN)

Comment: Nice one. Is there a version of this the other way around?

Comment: *a lil dreaming* **:** `$suffixes = array('B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');` I wants a Yottabyte hard drive! ***:-P***

Comment: i had to cast the $size to a double to get it to work. heres what worked for me: 
 function formatBytes($size, $precision = 2){
  $base = log(floatval($size)) / log(1024);
  $suffixes = array('', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T');   
  return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), $precision) . $suffixes[floor($base)];
 }

Comment: `formatBytes(259748192, 3)` returns `259748192 MB` which is not right

Comment: For the pedants amongst us (isn't that all of us?): 'K' should be 'k'. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix.

Comment: I like this too, and think it's clean, but a little more explaination about what this function is _doing_ in steps would be appreciated, for us noobs :). For example: why hard code `1024` instead of [using diff converters](http://www.eagle-web-designs.com/cool_stuff/ByteConversion.html) like `$unitInBytes = 1 * pow(2, 10)` then doing a `return ($size / $unitInBytes)` or some combination thereof, why does this method produce better results? Any clarification is appreciated for understanding it, rather than just copy/pasting and never thinking about it again.

Comment: It calculates bits $suffixes = array('', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T'); but if you want to show only minimum in Megabytes remove first 2 values $suffixes = array('M', 'G', 'T'); now calculate echo formatBytes(1024, 0); it will come up with 1GB

Comment: IDE looks nicer when added (int) here:    return .......$suffixes[(int)floor($base)];

Answer (score 97):

Pseudocode:

```
$base = log($size) / log(1024);
$suffix = array("", "k", "M", "G", "T")[floor($base)];
return pow(1024, $base - floor($base)) . $suffix;
```

Comment: Microsoft and Apple use 1024, it depends on your use case.

Comment: This doesn't look like pseudocode; or do you just mean that it is "untested code"? This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 19):

Just divide it by 1024 for kb, 1024^2 for mb and 1024^3 for GB. As simple as that.

Comment: Downvoted, because a) it's factually wrong (see ISO 80000-13), b) doesn't provide any real solution in the form of a piece of code.

Answer (score 16):

This is [Kohana's](http://v3.kohanaphp.com/guide/api/Text#bytes) implementation, you could use it:

```
public static function bytes($bytes, $force_unit = NULL, $format = NULL, $si = TRUE)
{
    // Format string
    $format = ($format === NULL) ? '%01.2f %s' : (string) $format;

    // IEC prefixes (binary)
    if ($si == FALSE OR strpos($force_unit, 'i') !== FALSE)
    {
        $units = array('B', 'KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB');
        $mod   = 1024;
    }
    // SI prefixes (decimal)
    else
    {
        $units = array('B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB');
        $mod   = 1000;
    }

    // Determine unit to use
    if (($power = array_search((string) $force_unit, $units)) === FALSE)
    {
        $power = ($bytes > 0) ? floor(log($bytes, $mod)) : 0;
    }

    return sprintf($format, $bytes / pow($mod, $power), $units[$power]);
}
```

Comment: Their idea of having an option between 1024 and 1000 power is good. But this implementation is really weird. `$force_unit` and `$si` seem to do the same thing. You can also pass any string with an "i" in it to `$force_unit`, because they test for position. The decimal formatting is also overkill.

Answer (score 9):

Just my alternative, short and clean:

```
/**
 * @param int $bytes Number of bytes (eg. 25907)
 * @param int $precision [optional] Number of digits after the decimal point (eg. 1)
 * @return string Value converted with unit (eg. 25.3KB)
 */
function formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2) {
    $unit = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB"];
    $exp = floor(log($bytes, 1024)) | 0;
    return round($bytes / (pow(1024, $exp)), $precision).$unit[$exp];
}
```

or, more stupid and efficent:

```
function formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2) {
    if ($bytes > pow(1024,3)) return round($bytes / pow(1024,3), $precision)."GB";
    else if ($bytes > pow(1024,2)) return round($bytes / pow(1024,2), $precision)."MB";
    else if ($bytes > 1024) return round($bytes / 1024, $precision)."KB";
    else return ($bytes)."B";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

use this function if you want a short code

[bcdiv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)

```
$size = 11485760;
echo bcdiv($size, 1048576, 0); // return: 10

echo bcdiv($size, 1048576, 2); // return: 10,9

echo bcdiv($size, 1048576, 2); // return: 10,95

echo bcdiv($size, 1048576, 3); // return: 10,953
```

Comment: The second bcdiv should have the third parameter as 1, not 2.

Answer (score 6):

Simple function

```
function formatBytes($size, $precision = 0){
    $unit = ['Byte','KiB','MiB','GiB','TiB','PiB','EiB','ZiB','YiB'];

    for($i = 0; $size >= 1024 && $i < count($unit)-1; $i++){
        $size /= 1024;
    }

    return round($size, $precision).' '.$unit[$i];
}

echo formatBytes('1876144', 2);
//returns 1.79 MiB
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's maybe a little late to answer this question but, more data is not going to kill someone. Here's a very fast function :

```
function format_filesize($B, $D=2){
    $S = 'BkMGTPEZY';
    $F = floor((strlen($B) - 1) / 3);
    return sprintf("%.{$D}f", $B/pow(1024, $F)).' '.@$S[$F].'B';
}
```

EDIT: I updated my post to include the fix proposed by camomileCase:

```
function format_filesize($B, $D=2){
    $S = 'kMGTPEZY';
    $F = floor((strlen($B) - 1) / 3);
    return sprintf("%.{$D}f", $B/pow(1024, $F)).' '.@$S[$F-1].'B';
}
```

Comment: You get a double B (BB) for small values of $B, as a work around you could make "$S = 'kMGTPEZY'", and instead of "@$S[$F]" do "@$S[$F-1]".

Comment: @camomileCase Two years and half later - I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Extremely simple function to get human file size.

Original source: http://php.net/manual/de/function.filesize.php#106569

Copy/paste code:

```
<?php
function human_filesize($bytes, $decimals = 2) {
  $sz = 'BKMGTP';
  $factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);
  return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$sz[$factor];
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a nice one, which I used. Simple enough if you understand some math, which probably is a valid assumption for programmers.
But: The factor should be 1000 to be correct, and this returns the quite uncommon PHP shorthand “42M”, not something one would use in UI like “42 MB“.

Comment: Too much math. Math is expensive :)

Answer (score 4):

```
function convertToReadableSize($size)
{
  $base = log($size) / log(1024);
  $suffix = array("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB");
  $f_base = floor($base);
  return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), 1) . $suffix[$f_base];
}
```

Just call the function

```
echo convertToReadableSize(1024); // Outputs '1KB'
echo convertToReadableSize(1024 * 1024); // Outputs '1MB'
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: pretty good but is missing some handling for $size=0

Answer (score 3):

Flexible solution:

```php
function size($size, array $options=null) {

    $o = [
        'binary' => false,
        'decimalPlaces' => 2,
        'decimalSeparator' => '.',
        'thausandsSeparator' => '',
        'maxThreshold' => false, // or thresholds key
        'suffix' => [
            'thresholds' => ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y'],
            'decimal' => ' {threshold}B',
            'binary' => ' {threshold}iB',
            'bytes' => ' B'
        ]
    ];

    if ($options !== null)
        $o = array_replace_recursive($o, $options);

    $base = $o['binary'] ? 1024 : 1000;
    $exp = $size ? floor(log($size) / log($base)) : 0;

    if (($o['maxThreshold'] !== false) &&
        ($o['maxThreshold'] < $exp)
    )
        $exp = $o['maxThreshold'];

    return !$exp
        ? (round($size) . $o['suffix']['bytes'])
        : (
            number_format(
                $size / pow($base, $exp),
                $o['decimalPlaces'],
                $o['decimalSeparator'],
                $o['thausandsSeparator']
            ) .
            str_replace(
                '{threshold}',
                $o['suffix']['thresholds'][$exp],
                $o['suffix'][$o['binary'] ? 'binary' : 'decimal']
            )
        );
}

var_dump(size(disk_free_space('/')));
// string(8) "14.63 GB"
var_dump(size(disk_free_space('/'), ['binary' => true]));
// string(9) "13.63 GiB"
var_dump(size(disk_free_space('/'), ['maxThreshold' => 2]));
// string(11) "14631.90 MB"
var_dump(size(disk_free_space('/'), ['binary' => true, 'maxThreshold' => 2]));
// string(12) "13954.07 MiB"
```

Answer (score 3):

My own implementation for getting formatted file size from integer size. Simple to understand and easy to extend to accommodate larger files - Just follow the pattern.

```php
<?php

function getFormattedFileSize($size, $precision) 
{
    switch (true) 
    {
        case ($size/1024 < 1):
            return $size.'B';
        case ($size/pow(1024, 2) < 1):
            return round($size/1024, $precision).'KB';
        case ($size/pow(1024, 3) < 1):
            return round($size/pow(1024, 2), $precision).'MB';
        case ($size/pow(1024, 4) < 1):
            return round($size/pow(1024, 3), $precision).'GB';
        case ($size/pow(1024, 5) < 1):
            return round($size/pow(1024, 4), $precision).'TB';
        default:
            return 'Error: invalid input or file is too large.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach

```
    function file_format_size($bytes, $decimals = 2) {
  $unit_list = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'PB');

  if ($bytes == 0) {
    return $bytes . ' ' . $unit_list[0];
  }

  $unit_count = count($unit_list);
  for ($i = $unit_count - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $power = $i * 10;
    if (($bytes >> $power) >= 1)
      return round($bytes / (1 << $power), $decimals) . ' ' . $unit_list[$i];
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation. I have concerns regarding `KB` and `KiB`. https://3v4l.org/s9AXo  Please see https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/4425

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you should make it so complicated as the others.

The following code is much simpler to understand and about 25% faster than the other solutions who uses the log function (called the function 20 Mio. times with different parameters)

```
function formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2) {
    $units = ['Byte', 'Kilobyte', 'Megabyte', 'Gigabyte', 'Terabyte'];
    $i = 0;

    while($bytes > 1024) {
        $bytes /= 1024;
        $i++;
    }
    return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ' . $units[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Albeit a bit stale, this library offers a *tested* and robust conversion API:

https://github.com/gabrielelana/byte-units

Once installed:

```php
\ByteUnits\Binary::bytes(1024)->format();

// Output: "1.00KiB"
```

And to convert in the other direction:

```php
\ByteUnits\Binary::parse('1KiB')->numberOfBytes();

// Output: "1024"
```

Beyond basic conversion, it offers methods for addition, subtraction, comparison, etc.

*I am no way affiliated with this library.*

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `log10`:

```
<?php

function format_number(float $d): string {
   $e = (int)(log10($d) / 3);
   return sprintf('%.3f', $d / 1e3 ** $e) . ['', ' k', ' M', ' G'][$e];
}

$s = format_number(9012345678);
var_dump($s == '9.012 G');
```

https://php.net/function.log10

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: Are you expecting float values as the incoming byte count?

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded with following function,

```
    function format_size($size) {
        $mod = 1024;
        $units = explode(' ','B KB MB GB TB PB');
        for ($i = 0; $size > $mod; $i++) {
            $size /= $mod;
        }
        return round($size, 2) . ' ' . $units[$i];
    }
```

Comment: Beware: K is for Kelvin and k is for kilos.

Comment: Instead of `$units = explode(' '...)` I'd guess you could simply use an array `$units = array( 'B', 'kB', 'MB'...)` — which could even be a constant or a static, outside the body of the function (`$mod ` might either be a constant or define).

Answer (score 1):

try this ;)

```
function bytesToSize($bytes) {
                $sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
                if ($bytes == 0) return 'n/a';
                $i = intval(floor(log($bytes) / log(1024)));
                if ($i == 0) return $bytes . ' ' . $sizes[$i]; 
                return round(($bytes / pow(1024, $i)),1,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP). ' ' . $sizes[$i];
            }
echo bytesToSize(10000050300);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeType($size, $type, $end){
    $arr = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
    $tSayi = array_search($type, $arr);
    $eSayi = array_search($end, $arr);
    $pow = $eSayi - $tSayi;
    return $size * pow(1024 * $pow) . ' ' . $end;
}

echo changeType(500, 'B', 'KB');
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I did this converting all input to byte and so converting to any output needed. Also, I used a auxiliar function to get base 1000 or 1024, but left it flex to decide use 1024 on popular type (without 'i', like MB instead of MiB).

```
    public function converte_binario($size=0,$format_in='B',$format_out='MB',$force_in_1024=false,$force_out_1024=false,$precisao=5,$return_format=true,$decimal=',',$centena=''){
    $out = false;

    if( (is_numeric($size)) && ($size>0)){
        $in_data = $this->converte_binario_aux($format_in,$force_in_1024);
        $out_data = $this->converte_binario_aux($format_out,$force_out_1024);

        // se formato de entrada e saída foram encontrados
        if( ((isset($in_data['sucesso'])) && ($in_data['sucesso']==true)) && ((isset($out_data['sucesso'])) && ($out_data['sucesso']==true))){
            // converte formato de entrada para bytes.
            $size_bytes_in = $size * (pow($in_data['base'], $in_data['pot']));
            $size_byte_out = (pow($out_data['base'], $out_data['pot']));
            // transforma bytes na unidade de destino
            $out = number_format($size_bytes_in / $size_byte_out,$precisao,$decimal,$centena);
            if($return_format){
                $out .= $format_out;
            }
        }
    }
    return $out;
}

public function converte_binario_aux($format=false,$force_1024=false){
    $out = [];
    $out['sucesso'] = false;
    $out['base'] = 0;
    $out['pot'] = 0;
    if((is_string($format) && (strlen($format)>0))){
        $format = trim(strtolower($format));
        $units_1000 = ['b','kb' ,'mb' ,'gb' ,'tb' ,'pb' ,'eb' ,'zb' ,'yb' ];
        $units_1024 = ['b','kib','mib','gib','tib','pib','eib','zib','yib'];
        $pot = array_search($format,$units_1000);
        if( (is_numeric($pot)) && ($pot>=0)){
            $out['pot'] = $pot;
            $out['base'] = 1000;
            $out['sucesso'] = true;
        }
        else{
            $pot = array_search($format,$units_1024);
            if( (is_numeric($pot)) && ($pot>=0)){
                $out['pot'] = $pot;
                $out['base'] = 1024;
                $out['sucesso'] = true;
            }
        }
        if($force_1024){
            $out['base'] = 1024;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function byte_format($size) {
    $bytes = array( ' KB', ' MB', ' GB', ' TB' );
    foreach ($bytes as $val) {
        if (1024 <= $size) {
            $size = $size / 1024;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    return round( $size, 1 ) . $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simplified implementation of the Drupal [format_size](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/format_size/7) function:

```
/**
 * Generates a string representation for the given byte count.
 *
 * @param $size
 *   A size in bytes.
 *
 * @return
 *   A string representation of the size.
 */
function format_size($size) {
  if ($size < 1024) {
    return $size . ' B';
  }
  else {
    $size = $size / 1024;
    $units = ['KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
    foreach ($units as $unit) {
      if (round($size, 2) >= 1024) {
        $size = $size / 1024;
      }
      else {
        break;
      }
    }
    return round($size, 2) . ' ' . $unit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on [Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510459/1877620), add

- Support for negative
- Support 0 < value < 1 ( Ex: 0.2, will cause log(value) = negative number )

If you want max unit to Mega, change to `$units = explode(' ', ' K M');`

---

```
function formatUnit($value, $precision = 2) {
    $units = explode(' ', ' K M G T P E Z Y');

    if ($value < 0) {
        return '-' . formatUnit(abs($value));
    }

    if ($value < 1) {
        return $value . $units[0];
    }

    $power = min(
        floor(log($value, 1024)),
        count($units) - 1
    );

    return round($value / pow(1024, $power), $precision) . $units[$power];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another answer, but I thought some of the posted codes were too much complicated, so here is the implementation I wrote:

```php
function display_size($bytes, $precision = 2) {
    static $units = [
        'TiB' => 1024 ** 4, // requires 64-bit build, otherwise comment out this line
        'GiB' => 1024 ** 3,
        'MiB' => 1024 ** 2,
        'KiB' => 1024
    ];

    foreach ($units as $unit => $value) {
        if ($bytes > $value) {
            return round($bytes / $value, $precision) . ' ' . $unit;
        }
    }

    return $bytes . ' B';
}
```

A few notes (so that this answer is not "missing its educational explanation"):

- Rather than the [pow() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php), I'm using the [exponentiation operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (available since PHP 5.6).
- I'm storing the `$units` array in a [static variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) (a technique called "memoization"), so it is generated only one time (at the first call of the function), instead of at every call of the function. (I benchmarked and yes, there is a small performance gain.)
- About the units based on powers of 10 (e.g. MB) vs based on powers of 2 (e.g. MiB), you may read [Byte#Multiple-byte units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units) on Wikipedia.
- You need a 64-bit build of PHP, otherwise the TiB unit (1,099,511,627,776) would exceed the [largest integer supported](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max) (2,147,483,647 on 32-bit builds). Also, `$bytes` would exceed that value with filesizes larger than 2 GB.

Comment: ...lovin' a good "educational explanation". ;)  A static variable declaration is not synonymous with memoization. "_[...] [memoisation is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls to pure functions and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20memoization%20or%20memoisation,the%20same%20inputs%20occur%20again.)_"

Answer (score -1):

It's a little late but a slightly faster version of the accepted answer is below:

```
function formatBytes($bytes, $precision)
{
    $unit_list = array
    (
        'B',
        'KB',
        'MB',
        'GB',
        'TB',
    );

    $bytes = max($bytes, 0);
    $index = floor(log($bytes, 2) / 10);
    $index = min($index, count($unit_list) - 1);
    $bytes /= pow(1024, $index);

    return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ' . $unit_list[$index];
}
```

It's more efficient, due to performing a single log-2 operation instead of two log-e operations.

It's actually faster to do the more obvious solution below, however:

```
function formatBytes($bytes, $precision)
{
    $unit_list = array
    (
        'B',
        'KB',
        'MB',
        'GB',
        'TB',
    );

    $index_max = count($unit_list) - 1;
    $bytes = max($bytes, 0);

    for ($index = 0; $bytes >= 1024 && $index < $index_max; $index++)
    {
        $bytes /= 1024;
    }

    return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ' . $unit_list[$index];
}
```

This is because as the index is calculated at the same time as the value of the number of bytes in the appropriate unit. This cut the execution time by about 35% (a 55% speed increase).

Answer (score -1):

Another condensed implementation which can translate to the base 1024 (binary) or base 1000 (decimal) and also works with incredibly large numbers hence of the use of the bc library:

```
function renderSize($byte,$precision=2,$mibi=true)
{
    $base = (string)($mibi?1024:1000);
    $labels = array('K','M','G','T','P','E','Z','Y');
    for($i=8;$i>=1;$i--)
        if(bccomp($byte,bcpow($base, $i))>=0)
            return bcdiv($byte,bcpow($base, $i), $precision).' '.$labels[$i-1].($mibi?'iB':'B');
    return $byte.' Byte';
}
```

Comment: Just a little side note; `bcpow()` will throw TypeError exception if `$base` and `$i` are not string values. Tested on PHP version 7.0.11.

Comment: Thanks! I added the string caster and fixed an offset bug :)

Answer (score -1):

I figured I would add a meshing of two submitters code (Using John Himmelman's code, which is in this thread, and using [Eugene Kuzmenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807115/php-convert-kb-mb-gb-tb-etc-to-bytes/24676538#24676538)'s code) that I'm using.

```
function swissConverter($value, $format = true, $precision = 2) {
    //Below converts value into bytes depending on input (specify mb, for 
    //example)
    $bytes = preg_replace_callback('/^\s*(\d+)\s*(?:([kmgt]?)b?)?\s*$/i', 
    function ($m) {
        switch (strtolower($m[2])) {
          case 't': $m[1] *= 1024;
          case 'g': $m[1] *= 1024;
          case 'm': $m[1] *= 1024;
          case 'k': $m[1] *= 1024;
        }
        return $m[1];
        }, $value);
    if(is_numeric($bytes)) {
        if($format === true) {
            //Below converts bytes into proper formatting (human readable 
            //basically)
            $base = log($bytes, 1024);
            $suffixes = array('', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');   

            return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), $precision) .' '. 
                     $suffixes[floor($base)];
        } else {
            return $bytes;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL; //Change to prefered response
    }
}
```

This uses Eugene's code to format the `$value` into bytes (I keep my data in MB, so it converts my data: `10485760 MB` into `10995116277760`) - it then uses John's code to convert it into the proper display value (`10995116277760` into `10 TB`).

I've found this really helpful - so my thanks to the two submitters!

Answer (score -1):

I developed my own function that convert human readable memory size to different sizes.

```php
function convertMemorySize($strval, string $to_unit = 'b')
{
    $strval    = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $strval));
    $val       = floatval($strval);
    $to_unit   = strtolower(trim($to_unit))[0];
    $from_unit = str_replace($val, '', $strval);
    $from_unit = empty($from_unit) ? 'b' : trim($from_unit)[0];
    $units     = 'kmgtph';  // (k)ilobyte, (m)egabyte, (g)igabyte and so on...


    // Convert to bytes
    if ($from_unit !== 'b')
        $val *= 1024 ** (strpos($units, $from_unit) + 1);


    // Convert to unit
    if ($to_unit !== 'b')
        $val /= 1024 ** (strpos($units, $to_unit) + 1);


    return $val;
}


convertMemorySize('1024Kb', 'Mb');  // 1
convertMemorySize('1024', 'k')      // 1
convertMemorySize('5.2Mb', 'b')     // 5452595.2
convertMemorySize('10 kilobytes', 'bytes') // 10240
convertMemorySize(2048, 'k')        // By default convert from bytes, result is 2
```

This function accepts any memory size abbreviation like "Megabyte, MB, Mb, mb, m, kilobyte, K, KB, b, Terabyte, T...." so it is typo safe.