# PHP filesize MB/KB conversion

Tags: php, file, filesize

How can I convert the output of PHP's `filesize()` function to a nice format with MegaBytes, KiloBytes etc?

like:

- if the size is less than 1 MB, show the size in KB
- if it's between 1 MB - 1 GB show it in MB
- if it's larger - in GB

Comment: [check this also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510434/php-format-bytes-to-kilobytes-megabytes-gigabytes)

Comment: if you are working with WordPress, you can use the shared function `size_format()`.

Comment: And if you're _not_ working with WordPress (I am!), you can always take a peek at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/size_format/ and copy the source code. It defines a few constants, but everything should be easy to understand; also, the WordPress code tries to deal with internationalisation/localisation, which may be overkill (and `number_format()` will do the job of pretty-formatting things at the end, instead of WP's own function).

Answer (score 334, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
<?php
// Snippet from PHP Share: http://www.phpshare.org

    function formatSizeUnits($bytes)
    {
        if ($bytes >= 1073741824)
        {
            $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
        }
        elseif ($bytes >= 1048576)
        {
            $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
        }
        elseif ($bytes >= 1024)
        {
            $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
        }
        elseif ($bytes > 1)
        {
            $bytes = $bytes . ' bytes';
        }
        elseif ($bytes == 1)
        {
            $bytes = $bytes . ' byte';
        }
        else
        {
            $bytes = '0 bytes';
        }

        return $bytes;
}
?>
```

Comment: This answer is more efficient than the others below. It avoids using the log function or successive division statements to identify the unit.

Comment: That is a brilliant solution, thank you for this awesome function - exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This function is actually not correct. 1KB is 1000Bytes, because Kilo is 1000.

Comment: Easy and to the point. Just make sure that the bytes value you are inputting into the function isn't already formatting using number_format. Lol. Couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work, and realized the commas were messing things up for me.

Comment: At last someone who writes _fast_ PHP code, avoiding all the pitfalls of calling the expensive math function! And, of course, it's trivial to understand. Simple code sometimes is _efficient_ code. And a nice touch using `number_format()`. In fact, it seems that WordPress itself uses a variant of your simple function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/size_format/

Answer (score 75):

Even nicer is this version I created from [a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187127/956397) I found:

```
function filesize_formatted($path)
{
    $size = filesize($path);
    $units = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');
    $power = $size > 0 ? floor(log($size, 1024)) : 0;
    return number_format($size / pow(1024, $power), 2, '.', ',') . ' ' . $units[$power];
}
```

Note from [filesize() doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

> Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit
>   integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for
>   files which are larger than 2GB

Comment: Why is it "nicer" tho? It does almost the same thing as my version, except that it'll return the wrong size for files over 2GB (plus the OP never asked for the remaining units of power).

Comment: @AlixAxel It is nicer, because it is half the size and still easy to read. Also I bet it is faster. But hey, it's not personal. I didn't think of it myself. Your version is cool too! Upvoted it ;)

Comment: Adnan posted the most verbose, but also the most efficient answer. Using the log function to identify the units is much slower than using simple inequalities. Even using successive division statements in a loop is much faster than using log

Comment: @PiTheNumber Consider note at [`filesize()` doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php): "Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB". For this and for many more reasons I don't quite believe that someone would ever use PHP to operate on files, which size is counted in `TB`, not mentioning higher scales. Plus, I doubt your function is faster than Alix Axel's as you're using `pow` function, similar in resources consumption to `log` used by Alix.

Comment: I didn't say it is faster or something. Only that it looks nicer. But just for fun I tried to make a benchmark but I don't got any usable results. I should not run it on codepad: http://codepad.org/o6cWsjIi

Answer (score 43):

A cleaner approach:

```
function Size($path)
{
    $bytes = sprintf('%u', filesize($path));

    if ($bytes > 0)
    {
        $unit = intval(log($bytes, 1024));
        $units = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB');

        if (array_key_exists($unit, $units) === true)
        {
            return sprintf('%d %s', $bytes / pow(1024, $unit), $units[$unit]);
        }
    }

    return $bytes;
}
```

Comment: This looks cleaner but using log to identify the units is much more costly than using a few simple inequalities.

Comment: @AliGangji: True, between 0.1% and 42% more costly to be precise (depending on which `if` condition `$bytes` falls into).

Comment: @AliGangji: To expand on my last comment, seems like for values <= 1023 bytes the log approach is on average ~40% slower *but* for 1024 and above I get consistent averages on the order of 0.1%. Interesting!

Comment: @AlixAxel Wouldn't that be, because PHP parser analyses `if` block bottom-top, i.e. starting from single (last) `else` and going up through all `elseif` until finally reaching first (in order) `if`? Just wandering, why you're getting such results?

Comment: @trejder: I only have one `if` statement in my code. And for values 1..1023 it is much slower than for any given value above that. I assume it has something to do with the `log` implementation of PHP (after all, I'm using a 1024 base).

Comment: I can't freaking believe you guys are aruging about the 'cost' of a logarithmic equasion in this much cleaner and more elegant answer. How did you even benchmark that difference? And, why not begin the function with a comparisson to >= 1024 before applying a unit appendix if the log ist so costly?

Comment: I too would be interested to see how you implemented the comparison tests.

Comment: This didn't work as well for me.  It reported a 2.85gb file as 2G, whereas Adnan's solution reports 2.66GB  (still not accurate, but closer)..
I'd take accuracy over a few less milliseconds of processing time.

Answer (score 18):

I think this is a better approach. Simple and straight forward.

```
public function sizeFilter( $bytes )
{
    $label = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB' );
    for( $i = 0; $bytes >= 1024 && $i < ( count( $label ) -1 ); $bytes /= 1024, $i++ );
    return( round( $bytes, 2 ) . " " . $label[$i] );
}
```

Comment: Perfect i can use that in my helper class, thx alot.

Answer (score 11):

This is based on @adnan's great answer.

Changes:

- added internal filesize() call
- return early style
- saving one concatentation on 1 byte

And you can still pull the filesize() call out of the function, in order to get a pure bytes formatting function. But this works on a file.

---

```
/**
 * Formats filesize in human readable way.
 *
 * @param file $file
 * @return string Formatted Filesize, e.g. "113.24 MB".
 */
function filesize_formatted($file)
{
    $bytes = filesize($file);

    if ($bytes >= 1073741824) {
        return number_format($bytes / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
    } elseif ($bytes >= 1048576) {
        return number_format($bytes / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
    } elseif ($bytes >= 1024) {
        return number_format($bytes / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
    } elseif ($bytes > 1) {
        return $bytes . ' bytes';
    } elseif ($bytes == 1) {
        return '1 byte';
    } else {
        return '0 bytes';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

All the answers to the question uses that 1 kilobyte = 1024 bytes which is **wrong! (*1 kibibyte = 1024 bytes*)**

since the question asks to convert file sizes, it should use that **1 kilobyte = 1000 bytes** (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy)

```
function format_bytes($bytes, $precision = 2) {
    $units = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB');

    $bytes = max($bytes, 0);
    $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1000));
    $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1);

    $bytes /= pow(1000, $pow);

    return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ' . $units[$pow];
}
```

Comment: This answer is the only one that is technically correct based on SI standards (except KB should be kB)  If you use 1024 as your divisor, then the units should be expressed as KiB, MiB, GiB, TiB, etc.

Answer (score 6):

This would be a cleaner implementation:

```
function size2Byte($size) {
    $units = array('KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');
    $currUnit = '';
    while (count($units) > 0  &&  $size > 1024) {
        $currUnit = array_shift($units);
        $size /= 1024;
    }
    return ($size | 0) . $currUnit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A complete example.

```
<?php
    $units = explode(' ','B KB MB GB TB PB');
    echo("<html><body>");
    echo('file size: ' . format_size(filesize("example.txt")));
    echo("</body></html>");


    function format_size($size) {

        $mod = 1024;

        for ($i = 0; $size > $mod; $i++) {
            $size /= $mod;
        }

        $endIndex = strpos($size, ".")+3;

        return substr( $size, 0, $endIndex).' '.$units[$i];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function calcSize($size,$accuracy=2) {
    $units = array('b','Kb','Mb','Gb');
    foreach($units as $n=>$u) {
        $div = pow(1024,$n);
        if($size > $div) $output = number_format($size/$div,$accuracy).$u;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getNiceFileSize($file, $digits = 2){
    if (is_file($file)) {
        $filePath = $file;
        if (!realpath($filePath)) {
            $filePath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $filePath;
        }
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);
        $sizes = array("TB", "GB", "MB", "KB", "B");
        $total = count($sizes);
        while ($total-- && $fileSize > 1024) {
            $fileSize /= 1024;
        }
        return round($fileSize, $digits) . " " . $sizes[$total];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Get the size in bytes
function calculateFileSize($size)
{
   $sizes = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'];
   $count=0;
   if ($size < 1024) {
    return $size . " " . $sizes[$count];
    } else{
     while ($size>1024){
        $size=round($size/1024,2);
        $count++;
    }
     return $size . " " . $sizes[$count];
   }
}
```