# Smarty Modifier filesize

Tags: php, size, smarty

I am using Smarty and one of my section shows file names, including dates, file size, last access etc...

I want to display the size of the file in K if less then 1024, in Mb if less than 1048576 etc...

The data (file info) comes from the database (name, file size, date etc...)

*ex:*

```
File             Mime       Size       Date 
Filename1.jpg    mime/jpg   14.1Kb     2011/12/12
```

Is there any modifier in Smarty that do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

create a file in the plugin directory called: `modifier.filesize.php`

then add this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Smarty plugin
 * @package Smarty
 * @subpackage PluginsModifier
*/

/**
 * Smarty replace modifier plugin
 * 
 * Type:     modifier<br>
 * Name:     filesize<br>
 * Purpose:  show the filesize of a file in kb, mb, gb etc...
 * 
 * @param string $ 
 * @return string 
*/
function smarty_modifier_filesize($size)
{
  $size = max(0, (int)$size);
  $units = array( 'b', 'Kb', 'Mb', 'Gb', 'Tb', 'Pb', 'Eb', 'Zb', 'Yb');
  $power = $size > 0 ? floor(log($size, 1024)) : 0;
  return number_format($size / pow(1024, $power), 2, '.', ',') . $units[$power];
} 
?>
```

then you can use: `{$filename.size|filesize}`

Answer (score 3):

assuming the size you are giving is originally in bytes,

try this:

```
{if $size lt 1024}
  {$size} bytes
{elseif $size lt 1048576}
  {$size / 1024}Kb
{else}
...
{/if}
```

Comment: is $size less than 1024 kilobytes?

Comment: why the downvote? this effectively solves op's question. given, book of zeus' answer is much more preferable. but please do explain.

Comment: `{if $size lt 1024}` means size in bytes not kb, therefore this is false information you give. please fix