# how to get each file size individually from directory PHP

Tags: php

can anyone help me to get each file size individually from a local directory ?.

```
 $files = scandir('soft');    
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo $file . "<br />";

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

```
 $files = scandir('soft');    
foreach($files as $file) {
 if (!in_array($file,array(".",".."))) 
  { 
    echo $file . "<br />";
    echo filesize('soft/'.$file) . ' bytes';
  }
}
```

Just need to keep in mind that [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) gets only the filenames in that dir, and not the relative path to it. that's why you need to use `'soft/'.$file` and not `$file`

Comment: `$file` -> `echo filesize('soft/'.$file) . ' bytes';` instead of `$filename` -> `echo filesize('soft/'.$filename) . ' bytes';`

Comment: sorry i was in a hurry, you are right, modified. Thanks !

Comment: thanks, but im having a issue, your code shows me 4096 bytes for every files and echoing two extra sizes which files are not exist.

Comment: try now, it removes the '.' and '..' from the foreach loop

Comment: @seblaze can u help me to get the file sizes in MB ?

Comment: sure . The function you need to look is : number_format, based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501427/php-filesize-mb-kb-conversion you can modify your code : number_format(filesize('tests/'.$file) / 1048576, 2);

Comment: @seblaze thanks very much. can u help me with one more thing please? i need to see the each file last modified date.. is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. It's something like : date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime('soft/'.$file)); From here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$files = scandir('.');
foreach($files as $file) {
  echo filesize($file) . " bytes<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `filesize($filename)` php function, it will give size in bytes