# Convert file size in MB from KB

Tags: codeigniter

I am done with uploading file in codeigniter. Saved information of uploaded file in DB.  I am getting file size in KB, now.

I want file size in MB.

Comment: This answer could help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501427/php-filesize-mb-kb-conversion

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve all data from uploaded file

```
$file = $this->upload->data();

print_r($file);//show array elements

$size_in_kb = $file[0]['file_size'];
$size_in_mb = $size_in_kb/1024;

echo 'File size in KB:'.$size_in_kb;
echo '<br>File size in MB:'.$size_in_mb;
```