# how to get real file size from remote url?

Tags: php, file, size, extract

I have a shortcode to extract info from a file using a URL when this is requested by code says that file is `410 MB`, but when this file is fully downloaded real file size is `390 MB`, some way of getting file size `390 MB` or a bit similar to end size?

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
curl_close($ch);
echo round( $size / '1000000', 2);
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote file size without downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/remote-file-size-without-downloading-file)

Comment: @Mohammad problem is solved, error was in my size conversion, isn't '1000000' is '1048576'

Comment: No possible duplicate here, because the question is not how to retrieve the filesize of a remote file. The real question is how to convert bytes into megabyte.

Answer (score 0):

Your byte conversion is wrong. It 's a math issue and not a php issue.

Since a single kilobyte (KB) are 1024 bytes you have to convert single bytes with the factor 1048576, because 1048576 bytes are 1 megabyte.

Have a look at [the accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501427/php-filesize-mb-kb-conversion).