# How do I get the maximum allowed RAM usage in *bytes* at runtime?

Tags: php, memory-limit

I have (for example) this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

It varies between scripts and settings. I need to get the **number of bytes** -- not the string '128M' -- at runtime.

I have no use of the string `128M`, and do not wish to code my own parser to turn that (and all other symbols supported) into bytes.

How do I get the raw maximum number of bytes currently allowed for the current script?

(I'm coding a mechanism which is going to notify me when a script approaches its maximum allowed RAM usage, prior to it exceeding this, in order to send useful health reports to myself. Once it's already hit the roof, there is a FATAL error and it doesn't log properly.)

Comment: For what it's worth, there're only three [suffixes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes) and they're won't change without prior advice. It's going to be an extremely simple parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
function conv2bytes($val) {
    $val = strtolower(trim($val));

    $unit = substr($val,-1, 1);
    $val = substr($val, 0, -1);

    if($unit=='g') $val *= 1024*1024*1024;
    else if($unit=='m') $val *= 1024*1024;
    else if($unit=='k') $val *= 1024;
    else return false;
    return $val;
}
```

And use the code below to get the ram usage

```
echo memory_get_usage(false); // only the used memory is reported
echo memory_get_usage(true); // get total memory allocated from system, including unused pages
```

> Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I explicitly said I didn't want. You are assuming that megabytes are always used, it's ugly, it's fragile, etc.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you should  try to set the fomat you want at the beginning? like...
`ini_set('memory_limit', 512000000);`
Then when you use `ini_set()`, it will return the format you set.

Comment: Yes, but then that requires the user to use that very human-unfriendly format. This needs to be independent of how the user set it.

Comment: uh... except this, I have no idea temporarily :(

Comment: I did find this, but it's just more of the same user-defined madness functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807115/php-convert-kb-mb-gb-tb-etc-to-bytes

Comment: Nevermind. I've concluded that this is yet another "lost cause". I'll just use bytes. Sigh.