# PHP convert bytes to correct units

Tags: php

I am using the `PHP` function https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510459/425964 written by `@Mef` https://stackoverflow.com/users/227532/mef to format bytes to kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes, etc.

The problem is that:

```
echo formatBytes(9287695, 2);
```

Returns `8.86 MB`. Should'nt it be `9.3 MB`? Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: 1 MB = 1024 KB, 1 KB = 1024 B

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be 9.3 MB, the bytes always result in less when converted to KB / MB etc, since it's multiplied by 1024.

So if byte number starts with 92.. it will never result in 9.3 MB

I suppose 8.86 is the correct value.

Comment: Funny `OSX` shows the file as: 9,289,033 bytes (9.3 MB on disk)

Comment: Hehe, that means that it shows Millions of Bytes, not Mega Bytes

Comment: Yeah, maybe a bug in `OSX`. :) LOL

Comment: OSX is perfectly OK, as it shows *MEGA*Bytes and not *MEBI*Bytes.

Answer (score 1):

9287695/1024/1024=8.86
9287695/1000/1000=9.30
1 MB = 1024 KB = 1024*1024 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Units of Memory

```
Bit=a 1 or 0  
Byte=8 Bits  
Kilobyte=1024 Bytes  
Megabyte=1024 Kilobytes  
Gigabyte=1024 Megabytes  
Terabyte=1024 Gigabytes
```

So 9287695 Bytes is infact 8.86 MB

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of confussion in IT world about distinguish Mebi* and Mega*, Kibi* and kilo*. You are actually perfectly right, as proper suffix for 8.86 should me "MiB" and not "MB".

It is because 1 MiB = 1024 KiB and 1 KiB = 1024 B.
But 1 MB = 1000 kB and 1 kB = 1000 B.

Thus confusion.

So 8.86 is OK (`(9287695/1024)/1024 = 8,857`) as long as it is `8.86 MiB`.

Plese refer here for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte