# Using filesize() to get the total file size of a directory and it's contents

Tags: php

I'm using filesize() to hopefully return the total file size of an image directory. The code returns a size of 24mb which I know is incorrect, the directory has around 200+mb of images. Any ideas?

```
<?
    $filename = '../uploads';
    echo (filesize($filename) / 1024) . ' mb';
?>
```

Comment: There are several solutions already on this site. You should take a look at [some existing answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+folder+size+site%3Astackoverflow.com) before posting a new question here. Perhaps someone has already provided a solution that will work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to get directory size : [source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#94566)

```
function dir_size($directory) {
    $size = 0;
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory)) as $file){
        $size += $file->getSize();
    }
    return $size;
}
```

format the return value with following function to get human readable value : [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18295950/1219200)

```
function format_size($size) {
    $mod = 1024;
    $units = explode(' ','B KB MB GB TB PB');
    for ($i = 0; $size > $mod; $i++) {
        $size /= $mod;
    }
    return round($size, 2) . ' ' . $units[$i];
}
```

Comment: one upvote for  [Rob Agar]!

Comment: Rob and me copied from same source : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#94566, upvote for `itsrool`

Comment: If I understood it correctly, WINAPI returns junk values in the SIZE fields of the FileAttributes struct, is this right?