# php type conversion format mb to kb or any other format

Tags: php, type-conversion, byte

Does anyone know how to convert a type which could be byte, kb, mb, gb etc to another type so for example i have the following

```
ini_get('upload_max_filesize')
```

// this could be in mb my value at the moment is 64m so I need to compensate for shorter abbreviations

and the value in mb I need to convert it to kb or any other type

```
Helper::convertType(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'), 'kb'); the kb coulb be bytes or gb
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510434/format-bytes-to-kilobytes-megabytes-gigabytes

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code as a helper to make it human readable:

```
    /** 
    * Converts bytes into human readable file size. 
    * 
    * @param string $bytes 
    * @return string human readable file size (2,87 Мб)
    * @author Mogilev Arseny 
    */ 
    function FileSizeConvert($bytes)
    {
    $bytes = floatval($bytes);
        $arBytes = array(
            0 => array(
                "UNIT" => "TB",
                "VALUE" => pow(1024, 4)
            ),
            1 => array(
                "UNIT" => "GB",
                "VALUE" => pow(1024, 3)
            ),
            2 => array(
                "UNIT" => "MB",
                "VALUE" => pow(1024, 2)
            ),
            3 => array(
                "UNIT" => "KB",
                "VALUE" => 1024
            ),
            4 => array(
                "UNIT" => "B",
                "VALUE" => 1
            ),
        );

    foreach($arBytes as $arItem)
    {
        if($bytes >= $arItem["VALUE"])
        {
            $result = $bytes / $arItem["VALUE"];
            $result = str_replace(".", "," , strval(round($result, 2)))." ".$arItem["UNIT"];
                break;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Or use this function to manually convert file sizes:

```
    function changeType($size, $from, $to){
        $arr = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
        $tSayi = array_search($to, $arr);
        $eSayi = array_search($from, $arr);
        $pow = $eSayi - $tSayi;
        return $size * pow(1024, $pow) . ' ' . $to;
    }

    echo changeType(1, 'MB', 'KB');
```

Comment: How can I just get it to convert MB to KB or just a specific type tho like iwant 64MB to in KB that's what I want the function to do

Comment: I wrote another function to convert any type of file size to any other file size type.
you can use that in your project.