# floor value in php function

Tags: php, mysql, floor

I have one android application in which I am using PHP API for get data from server. This is quote application and in which I have function of counting likes and shares of quotes. I am converting that count in k style number like 1K for 1000 etc with below function.

```
function Get_convert_to($value)
{
    if ($value > 999 && $value <= 999999) {
        $result = floor($value / 1000) . ' K';
    } elseif ($value > 999999) {
        $result = floor($value / 1000000) . ' M';
    } else {
        $result = $value;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Now my issue is its returning 1K for even 1400....I want 1.4K for 1400. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `floor()`...That function rounds the value downwards to the nearest integer value, in your example to 1...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format bytes to kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510434/format-bytes-to-kilobytes-megabytes-gigabytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get value like 1.4 (one decimal) use parameter to control decimal

```
<?php 
function Get_convert_to($value){


    if ($value > 1000) {
        $result = round(($value / 1000),1) . ' K';
    } elseif ($value > 999999) {
        $result = round(($value / 1000000),1) . ' M';
    } else {
        $result = $value;
    }


    return $result;
}

echo Get_convert_to(1400);
?>
```

Output:

`1.4K`

Comment: Hello ! Thats fine but number is not fixed 1400....it can be different every time

Comment: yes, off course. for `echo Get_convert_to(19256);` it will be `19.3 K`

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove `floor` because it will give you nearest lower value after division. ec 1.4/1.2 will become 1

```
function Get_convert_to($value){


    if ($value > 999 && $value <= 999999) {
    $result = ($value / 1000) . ' K';
} elseif ($value > 999999) {
    $result = ($value / 1000000) . ' M';
} else {
    $result = $value;
}


    return $result;
    }
```

Comment: hi ! in this case its giving me 1.025 K for 1025. I need only 1K for it. if 1050 then it will return 1.1 K etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want control the number of decimal you can use number format on division

```
  $result  =  number_format($value / 1000, 1, '.', '') . ' K'; ;
```