# Detect Image upload on Laravel through middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5, middleware

I'm looking at being able to have a image detect in a global `middleware` on `Laravel`.

My goal is to make the `middleware`, detect if there is currently an image being uploaded, and then detect its size and manipulate it.

Is this possible?

I've inherited a project, and need to manipulate every global image `upload`, but there are far too many individual scripts to change them all separately, I need some sort of way to change them all globally.

I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: Maybe you could change this one to make it work: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyPostSize.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ImageInterceptorMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach (array_flatten($request->files->all()) as $file) {
            $size = $file->getClientSize(); // size in bytes!

            $onemb = pow(1024, 2); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510446/6056864

            if ($size > $onemb) {
                abort(Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to actually handle the upload in the middleware, I just want to check its of a certain size before continuing. To do this, could I just have the top function, and return next request if the size it ok, to allow whatever controller made the request to finish the upload?

Comment: @S_R i have updated the middleware to check filesize instead

Comment: *note:* it checks the size of each file individually, and if any of them is to big the entire request gets blocked, not just that single file.

Comment: This seems to be checking the php.ini file for the allowed file size, not what is specified in the code. It returns `The file "picture.jpg" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB).`

Comment: @S_R no, you appear to have configured your php to only accept files up to 2 mb, only files below it get sent to this code. (you'd have to increase the default upload size)

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. Although the getClientSize() function is returning the error `Call to a member function getClientSize() on array`

Comment: Oh that is odd? could you try `$request->files->all()` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170376/discussion-between-s-r-and-quezler).