# I have problems with PHP and Laravel code

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem because this is not a clean solution how I calculate the things. Storage should be calculated in GB and Memory in MB I get values like `"free" => 98807345152` from the respective Storage and Memory. What is a better solution?

I don't like the calculations there.

```
$nodeMemory = GetNodeMemoryStatusAction::run('node01');
    $nodeStorage = GetNodeStorageStatusAction::run('node01');

    if (number_format($nodeMemory['free'] / 1024 / 1024, 0, ',', '') >= $this->data['memory']
        && number_format($nodeStorage['free'] / 1024 / 1024, 0, ',', '') >= $this->data['storage'] / 1024) {
    }
```

Comment: What do you "not like", exactly? It's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format bytes to kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510434/format-bytes-to-kilobytes-megabytes-gigabytes)

Comment: If you don't like dealing in bytes, create an interface with values you do like?