# How can I handle large files in my PHP-based video converter?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I have a video converter. Here's how it works, you give the URL to the video, it downloads it to the server, then it converts it to mp3. So it works, but the problem is anything over 10 MB (which is only about 30 seconds) crashes the server. I need to know how to upload it in parts, so it doesn't crash the server.

`file_put_contents($dest,file_get_contents($url));`

Comment: There are a number of reasons this could fail. What do error logs show?

Comment: The server I'm building this on is a free server. So, no error log...

Comment: Move to a real hosting service. Trying to build anything serious on a free hosting service will just end in pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to download content in chunks. A nice method for doing so can be found in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249279/file-get-contents-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-exhausted#5249971).  In the `$callback` function parameter, you can pass a method to convert and write bytes being read.

```
file_get_contents_chunked($url, 4096, function($chunk, &$handle, $iteration) {
    file_put_contents($dest, $chunk, FILE_APPEND);
});
```

Comment: @Jordan Make use of the `$callback` function; I've noted it in the answer now as well.

Comment: How would I save a part of a file?

Comment: Sorry, I'v only been using PHP for about a year now. Sorry for my noobness.

Comment: @Vulcan `memory_limit` is 128M by default. And you probably mean `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size`.

Comment: @Jordan Added to answer. Also, I've been using PHP for less than half a year; I've used Google for most of this answer--you should try it sometime :)

Comment: @Arjan Ah, good point. I've removed that portion of the answer as it's a bad approach regardless.

Comment: Also, the file size? Can I use filesize() before I upload it?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to get the file size *before* you download it, or after?

Comment: 4096 Is the file size. Don't I need that before?

Comment: Also error with your function: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/a1431054/public_html/Video/rename.php on line 46

Comment: if ($file != null && $fileExist == true && $test == false)
{
    file_get_contents_chunked($url,4096,function($chunk,&$handle,$iteration)
    {
        file_put_contents($dest, $chunk, FILE_APPEND);
    });
}

Comment: 4096 is just the chunk size I chose; it can be anything you want it to be.  That error shouldn't be occurring; try defining the callback function in a standard way and then passing it's name,

Comment: Well, it doesn't download... :/

Comment: This should be the last error. Thoughs? Warning: file_put_contents() [function.file-put-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/learntc/public_html/fiverr/Video/rename.php on line 44

Comment: @Jordan what PHP version are you using?

Comment: Okay, I just figured out, it's getting the file info, but it's not appending it.

Comment: Found the problem, the path is not working.. I tried echoing it? There's nothing there. I tried to change it, same thing..

Comment: Help me with the last error please! It works, I just need to know why variables don't work in the function?

Comment: @Jordan I can't say for sure without seeing any code; make sure you're referring to the correct variable.

Comment: Scope problems. Fixed Thanks everyone!