# Why so much memory needs PHP by multiple insertion to MySql DB?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, memory

I try to insert data from 15MB csv file (over 200 000 rows) to MySql.
I'm using CodeIgniter and inserting data row by row.
Now I have set memory_limit = 400M and I am able insert only about 100 thousand, then I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxxx bytes exhausted

I wonder how does it work, and what exactly allocates over 400MB memory when the file is 15MB and I insert data row by row always overwriting $data array with the new record?

Comment: Maybe you should show us your code. Without it is only suggestions.

Comment: i guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249279/file-get-contents-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-exhausted/5249971#5249971 could help you - if this doesnt work, you should post the entire code here...