# How can I process a large CSV file line by line?

Tags: php, large-files, fgetcsv, csv-import

I've successfully written a script that downloads a CSV file with the use of cURL and then parses the CSV into a array as follows:

```
$rows = array_map(function($a) {
    return str_getcsv($a, $delimiter);
}, explode("\n", $result));
```

Then I iterate over `$rows` using `foreach` to save something into the database.

The script works fine, but when using a larger CSV file (>10.000 lines), the script becomes rather slow and gives a lot more errors.

I would like to cut the CSV file into pieces, so not the whole file will be imported into a variable. I found the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249279/file-get-contents-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-exhausted/5249971#5249971), but that still processes the whole file at once.

Is there a method to cut the CSV into pieces and run the database function several times? Or is there a better way to process a large CSV file like this?

I'm relatively new to processing large files, so please be kind!

Comment: Maybe if you show a bit more of your code we might be able to be more helpful

Comment: Use the solution you linked to read the csv line by line and after every x lines you write them all to a file, clear memory and start a new file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save the file somewhere and then process it in chunks like this:

```
<?php
$filePath = 'big.csv';

//How many rows to process in each batch
$limit = 100;

$fileHandle = fopen($filePath, "r");
if ($fileHandle === FALSE)
{
    die('Error opening '.$filePath);
}

//Set up a variable to hold our current position in the file
$offset = 0;
while(!feof($fileHandle))
{
    //Go to where we were when we ended the last batch
    fseek($fileHandle, $offset);

    $i = 0;
    while (($currRow = fgetcsv($fileHandle)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $i++;

        //Do something with the current row
        print implode(', ', $currRow)."\n";

        //If we hit our limit or are at the end of the file
        if($i >= $limit)
        {
            //Update our current position in the file
            $offset = ftell($fileHandle);

            //Break out of the row processing loop
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Close the file
fclose($fileHandle);
```

Comment: If limit is bigger then quantity of rows we can: $chunkValOpt = [5000,1000, 500, 100, 10, 2, 1]; $chunk = 1;
            foreach ($chunkValOpt as $value){
                $result = $this->chooseChunkSize( $value, $filePath ) ;
                if($result != 0){ $chunk = $value; break; }
            }
//// chooseChunkSize( $value, $filePath ) - is nearly same function, which returns $tmp  counter, where the second while contains only:  $i++;if($i >= $chunk)$tmp++;