# How can i read large CSV file in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to read a CSV file that has 800000 line using PHP, but i got this Error:

```
Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)
```

How could i fix it?

Comment: you should read file in chunks please share the code what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: One simple google search can leads to direct answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520093/read-large-data-from-csv-file-in-php

Comment: A common cause is either reading the whole file in one go or storing all of the data in an array.  You need to process it as you go along (whenever possible).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file\_get\_contents => PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249279/file-get-contents-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-exhausted)

Comment: Did you read the CSV data then insert to database?

Answer (score 1):

You can read it by chunk.

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```